# How to add a main method to this program?

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

Hi I'm fairly new to coding and don't understand the required task I have to complete. How can I run the following code to make sure it works by adding a main method?

Answers and documents will be more than helpful, thank you.

```
public static boolean approxEqual (double x, double y)
{
        //Judge where two numbers are close enough (equal)
        final double EPSILON = 1E-10;
        if (Math.abs(x-y)<EPSILON)
        {
            return(true);
        }
    return(false);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're not to the point where you should be worrying about this yet.  I'd suggest you take a look at the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).  Start with "Getting Started" and take a look at some of the Hello World implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a class and add the main method to it as follows

```
public class Sol {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sol.approxEqual(1.0,1.2)
    }

    public static boolean approxEqual (double x, double y)
    {
        //Judge where two numbers are close enough (equal)
        final double EPSILON = 1E-10;
        if (Math.abs(x-y)<EPSILON)
        {
            return(true);
        }
        return(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run it, nothing shows in the console. Is that meant to happen?

Comment: @Dys You need to `print` it out if you want to see any results.  You really should look up some basic tutorials, and do some research, this information is all easily accessible.  Do `System.out.println(Sol.approxEqual(1.0,1.2));` to `print` it to console.

Comment: Try System.out.println(Sol.approxEqual(1.0,1.2));